# Missing Wiki Edit Tab

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Given a Site by Administrator - trying to use the Create Wiki page feature and don't have editing ribbon

This is my view

[image]

But I need to have this tool bar:

[image]

Comment: is wiki page feature activated?check that

Comment: Thanks Neal - how would I have our system administrator check that - I am able to create wiki pages - is there something else he needs to "turn on"  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, the wiki library you have is in a WSS v3 or MOSS 2007 environment.  The Ribbon interface was introduced in the SharePoint 2010 version of the product.  To get the Ribbon interface you will need to upgrade your SharePoint environment.

Comment: Thank you - no one at my new company understands sharepoint enough to troubleshoot and it is very frustrating